# Typo3 Extbase Repository->findAll() returns empty

Tags: extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I just can't [findAll()](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_repository.html#a73a1b0348919b6755e4f69dcc70eba64) make return anything even though I am able to access a specific record by [findByUid()](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_repository.html#a2a812a0fb6e57bf3b52655b400f9b1b1).

I have taken note (and tried to workaround / set up) of the [typoscript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602307/extbase-repository-findall-returns-result-null) and the [record storage page bug](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/58857#change-224537) without any success.

I am using a [dummy extension code made by the extension builder](http://typodrive.com/stackoverflow/mco_testimonials_0.2_201407202227.zip) in TYPO3 (current version) for your convenience. I have tested with data manually added through the TYPO3 config ui.

Any help would be much appreciated.

All the best and thanks in advance

Mario

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For 99.9 % you didn't set your storagePid properly, it has to be the PID of the page where your records are stored. Effect: `findAll()` uses this PID to filter the records, while `findByUid(uid)` ignores PID (it searches by UID wherever record is stored.

Go to the main page > Templates  and make sure that you included TypoScript from your new ext, then go to constant editor and set proper PID of page with your records. **Clear whole cache** at the end!

Also you can debug your SQL statement [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13085297/1066240), most probably at the end of statement you'll see something like `AND your_table_name.pid IN (0)` which definitely means that you didn't set `storagePid` or you didn't clear the cache.

Comment: Had the same issue. Simply forgot to include the TypoScript, which you also mentioned. Thanks!