# TYPO3 findAll returns empty

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I've got this in my controller:

```
/**
 * shopUsrMasterdataRepository
 *
 * @var 

\TYPO3\BackendcustomerExtension\Domain\Repository\ShopUsrMasterdataRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $shopUsrMasterdataRepository;

    $user = $this->shopUsrMasterdataRepository->findAll();
```

It Returns empty or null ... But in database there are abot 600 entries.

what could be the problem?

Using TYPO3 6.2.31

Thanks

Comment: Check if you have plugin.tx_yourext.persistence.storagePid set. Otherwise your query will be executed with WHERE ... AND pid=0 which will work only, if all your entries are stored in rootpage uid=0.

Comment: how can I figure out the correct storage pid? ... 

`$user = $this->shopUsrMasterdataRepository->findByEmail($fe_user)->getFirst();` this returns also null

Comment: See below, check TypoScript + have a look into your DB which values are set for pid at your ShopUsrMasterdata table

Comment: all records have pid 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typo3 Extbase Repository->findAll() returns empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854715/typo3-extbase-repository-findall-returns-empty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a pid (where the records are located) via TypoScript

```
plugin.tx_myext {
    persistence {
        storagePid = xxx
    }
}
```

or disable the requirement for a pid in your controller, e.g.:

```
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings $querySettings */
$querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings');
$querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
$this->myRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
```

Comment: Storeage pid is not set in typoscript of the extension. where do I disae it? in repository?

Comment: I've added the code in controller. but nothing changes

Comment: And what's the error message? I think we need more of your code to find problems

Comment: just an inetrnal error .. .nothing mentioned 

what do you need?

Answer (score 3):

In almost all cases this is caused by setting an incorrect `storagePageUid` in the persistence configuration for Extbase, in the scope that applies to your extension or backend module, whichever you are building.

Other possible causes can be use of record types (see FrontendUser domain model shipped with Extbase). If your domain model extends or uses `fe_user` then these considerations also apply to your case. Also, if you've declared `enableFields` on the TCA that applies to your table, these will be respected. If your table supports languages then the `sys_language_uid` also comes into effect. And finally: if you declared `hidden` or `delete` field these will also be respected.

If your use case demands that your TCA contains such `enableFields` but the plugin/module you build must not respect them, your option is to override `createQuery()` on Repository to manipulate the QuerySettings and force `respectEnableFields` or others to FALSE.

Edit: solution found, missing type mapping TS:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    Vendor\ExtKey\Domain\M‌​odel\Record.mapping {
        ​recordType = Tx_ExtKey_Domain_Model_Record`
    }
}
```

Comment: Yesterdy it works perfektly like above ... nothing changed since then

Comment: The selected storage page can be inherited from TS above, or can be defined in each plugin instance. I highly doubt that nothing was changed whatsoever - but I guess the challenge then is to determine *what* has been changed ;)

Comment: could thre be problems between typo3 versin 6.2.4 and 6.2.31? on 6.2.4 it works and on 6.2.31 not

Comment: That version jump does entail about three years of bug fix merges so I wouldn't be surprised if your setup somehow relied on a bug that has since been fixed. I'm afraid I can't point you to what exactly that might be, but you could always read the change log (all 27 of them).

Comment: We found the issue, it was a configured `config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.Vendor\ExtKey\Domain\Model\Record.mapping.recordType = Tx_ExtKey_Domain_Model_Record` that was not included in the type field generated by the extension_builder. Could you include that in your answer @ClausDue