# Extbase repository findAll() returns nothing

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

The `findAll()` finds nothing in my repository in a Method in my FE but it works in my BE.

```
public function showAction() {
    $p = $this->modulRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('pruefling',$p);
}
```

I tried to add

```
plugin.tx_rere.persistence.storagePid = 4
```

to my TypoScript Setup -> [extbase repository findAll() returns result null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602307/extbase-repository-findall-returns-result-null).
The table is not empty.

But it still does not work.

Comment: What is the PID of your entries? If you don't set any storagePID then 0 is used by default. Do you use only Frontend-Plugins or also Backend-Modules? You have to to set the storagePID for the module separately.

Comment: Check if the storagePid is correctly applied by using the TypoScript object browser.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of not giving the exact storage *pid*:

```
plugin.tx_urpluggin.persistence.storagePid = 4
```

To know whether you give the correct storage *pid*:

1. Go to Templatemodule
2. Select root template
3. Select typoscript object browser from top dropdown
4. Check the configurations in your plugin

If the storage *pid* is empty then click on that you will get a *typoscript*. Paste this into your main template.